# Can you use "knight moves" to query a single database and join it to itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, prolog

I am working on a project that involves code in both Prolog and SQL to solve the same problem. A problem I've run across is I can't use a single database to form a hierarchy. In this list of prolog facts you can see that the "assembly" parts are related to each other.

```
basicpart(spoke).
basicpart(rearframe).
basicpart(handles).
basicpart(gears).
basicpart(bolt).
basicpart(nut).
basicpart(fork).

assembly(bike,[wheel,wheel,frame]).
assembly(wheel,[spoke,rim,hub]).
assembly(frame,[rearframe,frontframe]).
assembly(frontframe,[fork,handles]).
assembly(hub,[gears,axle]).
assembly(axle,[bolt,nut]).
```

If I put all of these "assembly" definitions into one SQL database, can I use knight moves (joining a table to itself on 2 different columns in it) to build this hierarchy in SQL in only 2 tables?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but is there any reason why you couldn't use a so-called 'nested set' model

Comment: Sure? Maybe? You'd have to come up with a schema that is conducive to that, but it's doable.

Comment: "in only 2 databases" is confusing. Do you mean "using only two (table|relations)"? A "database" is generally a whole bunch of (table|relations), plus the necessary type definitions, plus the integrity constraints, plus views, plus triggers, plus stored procedure. This is of course unlike in Prolog, where a database is "just" the ensemble of facts and rules, all the same level (i.e. no internal organization or scoping - except for the modules)

Comment: As per Davids comment I changed the wording to table (I forgot my terminology). My question is what is the easiest way to make a table relational to itself? I'm trying join the different parts of the assembly which in this case is recursive (dealing in the same table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that question correctly. You cannot construct your bike with just one query (I'm not familiar with the term "knight moves"). In fact, you can -- but it must be a [recursive SQL query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL). Because you will be computing the transitive closure of the part-subpart relationship.

Unfortunately I don't immediately know how to write these. SQL syntax is frankly abysmal and recursive SQL looks even abysmaller, so below is example code using a loop instead.

You actually need only one table to represent the data as the `basicpart/1` relation does not bring anything to the table, except label certain "things" as basic. But these are *also* the things that do not appear in `assembly/2` in the first position.

Notes:

- Not using ENUMS which are not really "types" in MySQL/MariaDB but just a constraint on a field of a specific table. (Like, WTF!)
- The [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) representation of the Prolog code ("a bike has two wheels") is flattened into multiple rows separately identified by a numeric surrogate id. This is due to the ["First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)" dogma of RDBMS practice. There is à priori nothing wrong with having multisets as values, if the query language and the RDBMS engine can support it. For example, you can have XML values in PostgreSQL complete with queries over its content, as I remember<sup>1</sup>.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prepare;

CREATE PROCEDURE prepare() 
BEGIN

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assembly;

   CREATE TABLE assembly 
      (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,    -- surrogate key because a bike may have several wheels
       part VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
       subpart VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

   INSERT INTO assembly(part,subpart) VALUES
      ("bike","wheel"),
      ("bike","wheel"),
      ("bike","frame"),
      ("wheel","spoke"),
      ("wheel","rim"),
      ("wheel","hub"),
      ("frame","rearframe"),
      ("frame","frontframe"),
      ("frontframe","fork"),
      ("frontframe","handles"),
      ("hub","gears"),
      ("hub","axle"),
      ("axle","bolt"),
      ("axle","nut");
END;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS compute_transitive_closure;

CREATE PROCEDURE compute_transitive_closure()
BEGIN

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pieces;

   CREATE TABLE pieces
      (id      INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
       part    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
       subpart VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
       path    VARCHAR(500) NOT NULl DEFAULT "",
       depth   INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

   INSERT INTO pieces(part,subpart,path,depth) VALUES
      ("ROOT","bike","/bike",0);

   SET @depth=0;

   l: LOOP
      INSERT INTO pieces(part,subpart,path,depth)
      SELECT
         p.subpart,
         a.subpart,
         CONCAT(p.path,'/',a.subpart),
         @depth+1
      FROM
         pieces   p,
         assembly a
      WHERE
         p.depth = @depth AND p.subpart = a.part;

      IF ROW_COUNT() <= 0 THEN
         LEAVE l;
      ELSE
         SELECT * FROM pieces;
      END IF;

      SET @depth=@depth+1;
   END LOOP;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Put the above into a file `SQL.txt`, and then, in a database `testme`:

```
MariaDB [testme]> source SQL.txt;
MariaDB [testme]> CALL prepare;
MariaDB [testme]> CALL compute_transitive_closure;
```

Then after 4 passages through the loop, you get:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------------------------------+-------+
| id | part       | subpart    | path                           | depth |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | ROOT       | bike       | /bike                          |     0 |
|  2 | bike       | wheel      | /bike/wheel                    |     1 |
|  3 | bike       | wheel      | /bike/wheel                    |     1 |
|  4 | bike       | frame      | /bike/frame                    |     1 |
|  5 | wheel      | spoke      | /bike/wheel/spoke              |     2 |
|  6 | wheel      | spoke      | /bike/wheel/spoke              |     2 |
|  7 | wheel      | rim        | /bike/wheel/rim                |     2 |
|  8 | wheel      | rim        | /bike/wheel/rim                |     2 |
|  9 | wheel      | hub        | /bike/wheel/hub                |     2 |
| 10 | wheel      | hub        | /bike/wheel/hub                |     2 |
| 11 | frame      | rearframe  | /bike/frame/rearframe          |     2 |
| 12 | frame      | frontframe | /bike/frame/frontframe         |     2 |
| 20 | frontframe | fork       | /bike/frame/frontframe/fork    |     3 |
| 21 | frontframe | handles    | /bike/frame/frontframe/handles |     3 |
| 22 | hub        | gears      | /bike/wheel/hub/gears          |     3 |
| 23 | hub        | gears      | /bike/wheel/hub/gears          |     3 |
| 24 | hub        | axle       | /bike/wheel/hub/axle           |     3 |
| 25 | hub        | axle       | /bike/wheel/hub/axle           |     3 |
| 27 | axle       | bolt       | /bike/wheel/hub/axle/bolt      |     4 |
| 28 | axle       | nut        | /bike/wheel/hub/axle/nut       |     4 |
| 29 | axle       | bolt       | /bike/wheel/hub/axle/bolt      |     4 |
| 30 | axle       | nut        | /bike/wheel/hub/axle/nut       |     4 |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------------------+-------+
```

<sup>1</sup>: This made me dig out ["Database in Depth: Relational Theory for Practitioners"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100124.do), O'Reilly 2005, by [Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date), an excellent introduction to the relational model. On page 30, Date considers "sets as values" (but does not consider "multisets"):

> Second (and regardless of what you might think of my first argument),
>   the fact is that a set like `{P2,P4,P5}` is no more and no less
>   decomposable by the DBMS than a character string is. Like character
>   strings, sets do have some inner structure; as with characters
>   strings, however, it's convenient to ignore that structure for certain
>   purposes. In other words, if a character string is compatible with the
>   requirements of 1NF - that is, if character strings are atomic - then
>   sets must be, too. The real point I'm getting at here is that the
>   notion of atomicity has no absolute meaning; it just depends on what
>   we want to do with the data. Sometimes we want to deal with an entire
>   set of part numbers as a single thing, and sometimes we want to deal
>   with individual part numbers within that set - but then we are
>   descending to a lower level of detail (a lower level of abstraction).

Comment: Legend, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for the help!!